# Invalid v2 service endpoint for content-service

Tags: dxa, web8, content-service

I'm trying to set up my first DXA / Web 8 Installation, and i'm met with the following error when hitting the web app:

> Invalid v2 service endpoint for content-service
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.InvalidServiceEndpoint:
>   Invalid v2 service endpoint for content-service
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidServiceEndpoint: Invalid v2 service endpoint for
>   content-service]
>   Sdl.Web.Delivery.ContentService.AutoConfigure.get_ODataV2ServiceEndpoint()
>   +180    Sdl.Web.Delivery.ContentService.ContentServiceClient..ctor(IContentServiceConfiguration
>   serviceConfiguration) +96
>   Sdl.Web.Delivery.Dynamic.DynamicMappingsRetrieverImpl.GetPublicationMapping(String
>   url) +191
>   Sdl.Web.Tridion.CdApiLocalizationResolver.ResolveLocalization(Uri url)
>   in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App
>   .NET\Sdl.Web.Tridion\CdApiLocalizationResolver.cs:67
>   Sdl.Web.Mvc.Configuration.WebRequestContext.get_Localization() in
>   c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App
>   .NET\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Configuration\WebRequestContext.cs:23
>   Sdl.Web.Mvc.Statics.StaticContentModule.BeginRequest(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App
>   .NET\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Statics\StaticContentModule.cs:85
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +92    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +165

I've checked the configs and the urls of my content services and these seem to be correct, i'm wondering what i'm missing?

The Web App log is showing:

> ```
>   Registering OData V2 Service:
> ```
>
> http://localhost:8083/client/v4/content.svc/ 2016-03-07 16:56:21 WARN
>   [Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.<>c__DisplayClass21`1.<Execute>b__1f] -
>   Failed to execute query. 2016-03-07 17:05:15 INFO
>   [Sdl.Web.Delivery.Dynamic.DynamicMappingsRetrieverImpl.GetPublicationMapping]
>   - Creating content-service client. 2016-03-07 17:05:15 INFO [Sdl.Web.Delivery.ContentService.ContentServiceClient..ctor]
>         Registering OData V2 Service:
>   http://localhost:8083/client/v2/content.svc/ 2016-03-07 17:05:15 INFO
>   [Sdl.Web.Delivery.ContentService.ContentServiceClient..ctor]
>         Registering OData V2 Service:
>   http://localhost:8083/client/v4/content.svc/ 2016-03-07 17:05:15 WARN
>   [Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.<>c__DisplayClass21`1.b__1f] -
>   Failed to execute query.

This URL does correctly load my content service.

Any steps to trouble shoot this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Solved it, I re-ran:

`Java –jar discovery-registration.jar update` located in the `/config` folder of my discovery service

:)